# ASP.NET Best Practice for Table

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, performance

I am working on a ASP.NET Core Project with a table that I have filters for based off the current tab they are on. My initial thought was use JSON to call the C# and get the list of the the qualified items for the table.

My next plan I got thinking is maybe get the list of the all of the qualified items and then use a filter in a for loop?

```
    public JsonResult OnGetGetSetups(string condition,int vehID)
    {
        if (vehID == 0)
            return null;

        switch (condition)
        {
            case "Dirt":
                return new JsonResult(_context.Setups.Include(d => d.Driver).Include(sd => sd.SetupDetails).Include(c => c.SetupDetails.Condition).Where(a => a.SetupDetails.Condition.Name == condition && a.VehicleId == vehID).ToList());
            case "Carpet":
                return new JsonResult(_context.Setups.Include(d => d.Driver).Include(sd => sd.SetupDetails).Include(c => c.SetupDetails.Condition).Where(a => a.SetupDetails.Condition.Name == condition && a.VehicleId == vehID).ToList());
            default:
                List<Setup> tmp = _context.Setups.Include(d => d.Driver).Include(sd => sd.SetupDetails).Include(c => c.SetupDetails.Condition).Where(a => a.VehicleId == vehID).ToList();
                return new JsonResult(tmp);
        }
    }
```

Then I have 3 eventListeners that call this `GetSetups`. It just seems like a very messy way to solve this problem.

**Is there a better way to approach this?**

Something similar to this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#allSetups").on("click", function () {
        if (activeTab == "allSetups") {
            return;
        }
        activeTab = "allSetups";

        $("#infoArea").empty();
        var vehId = document.getElementById('vehicleId').value;
        var url2 = '@Url.Page("/setups/search","GetSetups")';
        $.getJSON(url2, { condition: "all", vehID: vehId }, (data) => {
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                $("#vehcileId").append(`<option value="${item.vehicleId}">${item.name}</option>`);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
    public JsonResult OnGetGetSetups(string condition, int vehID)
    {
        if (vehID == 0)
            return null;

        return new JsonResult(_context.Setups.Include(d => d.Driver)
                                             .Include(sd => sd.SetupDetails)
                                             .Include(c => c.SetupDetails.Condition)
                                             .Where(a => a.VehicleId == vehID
                                                        && ((condition != "Dirt" && condition != "Carpet") || a.SetupDetails.Condition.Name == condition))
                                             .ToList());
    }
```